# MySQL - Where/Having Count > columnName

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a list of dates called listings where people can signup to take part called a booking.

```
listings
id |    date    | capacity
1    2010-01-01   3
2    2010-01-02   1
3    2010-02-02   2

bookings
id | listing_id | name
1    1            Chris
2    1            Steve
3    1            Allen
4    2            Tracy
```

What I want to do is have a query which returns only the open listings based on the bookings.

Query would only return the listing with id = 3. Since it has no bookings and a capacity of 2.

```
Sample query which won't work:
SELECT
    *
FROM
    listings
HAVING COUNT(
             SELECT * FROM bookings WHERE listings.id=bookings.listing_id
            ) < capacity
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *
FROM listings
WHERE capacity > (SELECT count(*) 
                  FROM bookings 
                  WHERE listings.id=bookings.listing_id)
```

Comment: That will work, but the subquery will run as many times as there are rows.

Comment: with an index on bookings.listing_id that shouldn't be a significant performance hit.

Answer (score 0):

*Myself, I would do a join and then count:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as count 
FROM listings, bookings 
WHERE listings.id=bookings.listing_id 
AND count < listings.capacity 
GROUP by listings.id
```

I haven't tested it but that's the general idea!

Comment: @StevieG -- thanks for the edit!  Also welcome comment from whoever downvoted.

Comment: no probs. I didn't downvote you, but there are a couple problems with your answer. 1. It returns a count instead of the listing details. 2. The join will exclude listings with no bookings. 3. I don't think you can use an alias `count` in a where clause like that, should be count(*), or better again, use HAVING

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    listings.id,
    max(listings.date),
    max(listings.capacity)
FROM listings
left join bookings on listings.id = bookings.listing_id
group by listings.id
having COUNT(bookings.listing_id) < max(listings.capacity)
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Just out of curiosity why use max?

Comment: Because all fields are grouped by listings.id, so you need an aggregation to access other values. There will be only one value for capacity for the group (by id).